# Qt Blocking thread until condition met

Tags: multithreading, qt

```
class Driver : Public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    // method command: sends a command
    // signal ok: command executed, sends back a message
    MyDevice *device;


public:

    Deriver()
    {
        device = new MyDevice(0);
        connect (mydevice,&MyDevice::ok,this,&Driver::onInitOk);
    }

public slots:   
    void init()
    {
        device->command("init");
        //at this point, I want to block this method until the device signals ok with a given msg
    }

    command()
    {
        device->command("setmode x");
        device->command("cmd");
        //at this point, I want to block this method until the device signals ok with a given msg   
    }

    void onInitOk(QString msg)
    {
        //somehow unblock the actually running command, if the msg matches
    }   

}
```

I would like to use the command/init with a QueuedConnection, so they are executed async from the gui thread, and sequentially. (Am I right?)

How can I implement the blocking effectively?

Comment: Instead of blocking, why don't you just react on the message you get?

Comment: I dont see, how QWaitCondition could be used here.

Comment: I want the unblock as a reaction, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've edited based on the clarity of the comments given. The best place to look at would be the [Qt Threading Guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads.html). This can give a much better breakdown on the systems used for concurrency.

For your example I've added a QMutex object to your Driver class. It may be worth thinking about if you want to move the thread-based controls into the MyDevice class itself if you have access.

```
Driver()
{
     moveToThread(new QThread());
     device = new MyDevice(0);
}

void init()
{
    mutex.lock(); 
    const QString& result = device->command("init");
    onInitOk(result);
}

void command()
{
    mutex.lock();
    device->command("setmode x");
    const QString& result = device->command("cmd");
    onInitOk(result);
}

void onInitOk(QString msg)
{
  ...[STUFF]
  // Even when things go wrong you MUST unlock the mutex at some point.
  // You can't keep the thread blocked forever in cases of poor results.
  // As such it might be better practice to unlock in
  // the same function that locks!
  mutex.unlock();
}

QMutex mutex;
```

Bear in mind I am assuming you are wanting to access the functionality from the slots mechanism. Hence why we use the moveToThead() function. When the object is accessed via slots in the GUI thread it'll now run the function on a different thread.

Likewise the mutex only blocks for all the objects that share that one mutex instance. So depending on your implementation you may have to think about what is right for you in exposing that mutex.

Comment: What are those "actual libraries provided by Qt"? What I want to achive, is to be non blocking, and avoid concurrent access to the same device. Performance is not an issue.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Okay your needs are a bit more clear now. Your best bet is to use a QMutex object.

Comment: I know about the QMutex functionality, but its not trivial, how to use it in that case.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I've added an example based on your implementation, does that help?

Comment: The main problem with this implementation is, that it is not guaranteed that the first locked command gets unlocked. It was not entilrely clear, but I have to support multiple commands.

Comment: And one more thing: Those commands does not provide immediate results, so I can't return it. (the interface is a serial port)

Comment: Quick clarification: is it multiple drivers accessing one Device object? If so then the synchronization mechanism really needs moved into the Device objects themselves!

Comment: No, there is one Driver object and one device. The onInitOk supposed to be a callback, that is called by the device, in case it receives any message.